# Query to check for free disk space and send an alarm if the disk space exceeds threshold value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I would like to create a job which sends an email alert when my server disk space goes beyond a specific threshold value.Since my data files are bigger there is very little free space on disk partitions.

> Is is possible to write a Query which checks all the disks for the
>   free disk space and give an email alert if the disk space goes below
>   the set threshold value?

Comment: which edition of SQL server is there in your environment?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan, MS SQL 2008R2 standard edition with SP1

Comment: ,I am not asking about version. what edition you are using ( like Enterprise,Standard, Express etc).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article:
[Disk Space Monitoring: How To](http://sqlmag.com/blog/disk-space-monitoring-how)

And do not forget to monitor other crucial metrics: log file usage, cpu, blocking and so on...

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to write a Query which checks all the disks for the
>   free disk space and give an email alert if the disk space goes below
>   the set threshold value?

As per your question i have bifurcated into two parts.

> Is is possible to write a Query which checks all the disks for the
>   free disk space?

As per Pinal Dave Blog [Here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/08/02/sql-server-disk-space-monitoring-detecting-low-disk-space-on-server/) Through below mention TSQL query you can check your all disk drives space(in MB).

```
exec master..xp_fixeddrives;
Go
```

> And give an email alert if the disk space goes below the set threshold
>   value?

As per schneider Blog [Here](http://www.schneider-electric.com/en/faqs/FA238358/) Through stored procedure with scheduler job you can get  `SQL Server Disk Space Monitor Alerts`.

Note: - without testing in Test environment . Don't apply directly in Production environment.